# how to send iPhone Push Notification to Multiple Devices.?

Tags: php, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am getting a device token from database, but the notification which is sent successfully, its just receiving to the latest device in database.

But I have 3 devices tokens in my database.

```
if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'badge' => 1,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );
// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);
// Build the binary notification
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DeviceToken FROM iOS");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $deviceToken=$row['DeviceToken'];   
    echo $deviceToken;
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
}
// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered '.PHP_EOL;
// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
echo "<script>alert('Notification Sent Successfuly!'); location.href='Pushnotification.php';</script>";
```

Comment: " latest device" means ?

Comment: latest device mean when application instal on new iPhone and my db get new device-token then after that when i send push notification notification just receive on latest device token...

Answer (score 0):

put this line in while loop

```
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
```